# error about make

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I would like to use DDC card 1553-MIL-STD on Ubuntu 15.04.

When making the project, I have the following error. What should I do?

```
root@rdp-OptiPlex-9020:/home/rdp/DDC/BU69092S1_3_13_0/samples/emacepl/prj# make

================================================================
Remove Samples and ddc_os_lib_util
================================================================
rm -f ddc_os_lib_util.o
rm -f ../bin/test.vec
for prog in aesdemo aio bcasync bcasync2 bcdbuf bcdemo bcei bcimr bcmemobj bcmrt bcmrtmti bcmti bcopcode bctime datarray datastrm dbcdemo dio dioall irigdemo looptest mrtdemo mrtei mrtimr mrtmti mti2disk mti2dsk2 mtidemo mtiedemo mtiread mtiread2 mtirq mtpoll replaydemo resptime rtdataarray rtdbuf rtirq rtmode rtmtdemo rtmtidemo rtpoll tester trgdio trigger voltage; do \
    rm -f ../bin/$prog; \
done

================================================================
Build Samples
================================================================
mkdir -p ../bin
gcc -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/emacepl -I/usr/include/ddcacex -I/usr/include/ddcacex/os/lib_support -DLINUX -DDDC_LINUX_THREAD -lpthread -lemacepl -c /usr/include/ddcacex/os/lib_support/ddc_os_lib_util.c -o ddc_os_lib_util.o
gcc -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/emacepl -I/usr/include/ddcacex -I/usr/include/ddcacex/os/lib_support -DLINUX -DDDC_LINUX_THREAD -lpthread -lemacepl ../src/aesdemo/aesdemo.c -o ../bin/aesdemo ddc_os_lib_util.o  -I/usr/include/emacepl -I/usr/include/ddcacex -I/usr/include/ddcacex/os/lib_support -DLINUX -DDDC_LINUX_THREAD -lpthread -lemacepl 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libemacepl.so when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libemacepl.a when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libemacepl.so when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libemacepl.a when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libemacepl.so when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libemacepl.a when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libemacepl.so when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libemacepl.a when searching for -lemacepl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lemacepl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:109: recipe for target 'aesdemo' failed
make: *** [aesdemo] Error 1
root@rdp-OptiPlex-9020:/home/rdp/DDC/BU69092S1_3_13_0/samples/emacepl/prj#
```

Answer (score 0):

When compiling the sources, the `-l` refers to libraries that your project should be linked with.

In your example, the makefile tries to build `'aesdemo'` and needs to link with `'emacepl'` library but it cannot find it.

```
cannot find -lemacepl
```

Either `'emacepl'` is not installed, either it cannot be found in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (where the makefiles looks for the different libraries).